# what are the extended features using System.Text.Json(.netcore-3.0) instead of Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have used Newtonsoft.Json for converting JSON object to string and vice versa. Recently I read about **`System.Text.Json`** in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.0.

I read the article and it is faster than **Newtonsoft.Json**.

**using Newtonsoft.Json;**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
Product product = new Product();    
product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };    
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

**using System.Text;**

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

Product product = new Product();    
product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" }; 
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(product);

var objproduct = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Product>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Unless there’s something stopping you sure you can

Comment: .NET Core 3.0 is a release version, so why not?

Comment: You should read this article, including the comments: https://michaelscodingspot.com/the-battle-of-c-to-json-serializers-in-net-core-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html escaping by default in System.Text.Json is one example of a difference.

Null values and circular references handling are some other differences.

System.Text.Json does not serialised fields as of .NET Core 3.0.

System.Json.Text is not a one to one replacement for Json.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Nobody is blocking you, unless you are getting some issues.
But in a project there will be some guidelines, so it is better to follow the guidelines, if you are implementing something new, its better to discuss with the team and then implement.